# SafeArea is not padding enough to avoid the notch

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

According to Documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html). SafeArea should keep the content away from the notch in iPhone X and similar devices but its not working on my pixel3 XL virtual device (I cannot test it on Physical android device as my phone has a pop up camera). Is this feature exclusively for IOS ? Is there any other way to keep my content away from the notch irrespective of the OS and notch dimensions ?

> Here's my Code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "SafeArea Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Roboto'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Home(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        setBackGround(),
        SafeArea(
          child: Text(
            "Pramod Pardeshi",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFEFEFE), fontSize: 25),
            textScaleFactor: 1.5,
          ),
        ),
        //setGrid(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

> Here's how it look.

[image: Pixel3 XL]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap the whole App or at least the Scaffold widget in a Safearea widget.

If that doesn't work it is possible that the emulator that you are using is not reporting its notch. On an actual phone it should work.

Comment: I would agree with that answer, cause status bar is the same height as notch on real devices

Answer (score 0):

@MindStudio is right. found this [article](https://medium.com/@hiteshdhamshaniya.wvmagic/notch-android-emulator-with-p-e9b3556d9d5e) on medium. according to it notch has to be enabled from developers options though it can only be done for AVD with android P. there is no mention of lower versions anywhere else, as I was using android Oreo I thought may be that's an issue. I updated it to android Q and It worked!

[image]